# ResXResourceWriter Chops off end of file

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I'm trying to create a .resx file from a dictionary of strings.  Luckily the .Net framework has a ResXResourceWriter class.  The only problem is that when I create the file using the code below, the last few lines of my generated resx file are missing.  I checked my Dictionary and it contains all the string pairs that I expect.

```
public void ExportToResx(Dictionary<string,string> resourceDictionary, string fileName)
{
    var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(fileName);

    foreach (var resource in resourceDictionary)
    {
        writer.AddResource(resource.Key, resource.Value);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it is a little difficult to show the entire resx file since it has 2198 (should have 2222) lines but here is the last little bit:

```
...
2195    <data name="LangAlign_ReportIssue" xml:space="preserve">
2196        <value>Report an Issue</value>
2197    </data>
2198    <data name="LangAlign_Return
```

BTW, notice that the file cuts off right at the end of that "n" in "LangAlign_Return".  The string should read "LangAlign_ReturnToWorkspace".  The file should also end at line 2222.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void ExportToResx(Dictionary<string,string> resourceDictionary, string fileName)
{
    using(var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(fileName))
    {
        foreach (var resource in resourceDictionary)
        {
            writer.AddResource(resource.Key, resource.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You needed to call Dispose() on the writer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does "LangAlign_ReturnToWorkspace" actually say that, or is it "LangAlign_Return ToWorkspace"?

(With a space or perhaps a non-printing character between Return and ToWorkspace?)

Maybe that is causing the elememt name to be generated wrongly?

Just an idea.

Comment: I just double checked this suggestion but there are no non-printing characters before or after in this string.  When I read your suggestion I half expected it to be the problem.

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: Ah, too bad, worth a try. Does it present the same error if you only put this value in the Dictionary?

Comment: I edited the XML file that I used to create the Dictionary (ensuring any strange chars remain) down to the offending entry.  I also kept all of the other entries that were below this one.  The file was cut off in a different spot and in the middle of one of the XML attributes.  So, I know that it isn't my strings because it cut off at a spot that was created by the ResXResourceWriter class.  Hmmm, I wonder what is up with this.  My code could not be more simple.